# Controlling Gnome-shell Notifications Message Tray

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I am using gnome-shell with 12.04 and find the notification system very disruptive and cumbersome. A suggestion from a previous post was to turn off notifications in the User menu, which appears to work, but this mysteriously gets turned back on with no input from me.

[image]

Is there a way to better control the tray and keep these popups from happening?

Comment: BTW, just noticed that if I turn notifications off in the user menu, it makes me "busy" by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes when you turn it off it will make your status busy. if you dont want to have any notification then try removing it 
try Alt + F2

type

```
gnome-tweak-tool
```

then go to shell extensions and turn it `Message Notification Extension` off

Comment: I don't appear to have a Message Notification Extension